# How to save data in the Azure cloud per server that dissappears when the server is down

Tags: azure

I have a server (Can run in Azure or locally) that uses Azure Service Bus (So it has already an Azure account).

I would like to save (small) data per each server in the cloud, that will disappear when the server no longer runs.

I know I can erase the data (Storage file?) when the server goes down properly but what about when the server crashes unexpectedly?

Is there a way to implement such thing using Azure? Is there a way to set expiration time limit for a file\data in the Azure Storage file (or some other Azure feature)?

(Not interested in using VM's for that).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the temp drive attached to the VM.

It is typically the D: drive on Windows VMs and /dev/sdb1 on Linux VMs.

This drive exists on the VM host so if your VM is deallocated or moved to another host for any reason, the contents are wiped.

More info here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2013/12/06/understanding-the-temporary-drive-on-windows-azure-virtual-machines/

Comment: thanks, I am looking for a way without using VM's
Thought of creating a file storage that each server could have a file there (file name = server's name) and each server will write a timestamp every x seconds to the file. This way, we could iterate the files, and see which server is still running. Sounds logical...?

Comment: You should specify that in the question.